# Display same column multiple times on one row

Tags: mysql, subquery

i'm trying to display the same column three times with different values, but can't seem to get the code. right.

I have three tables
Projectdetails (projectID), projectroles (projectroleID), projectstaff (projectstaffID)
Projectdetails

```
+-----------+-------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
| ProjectID | ProjectCode | ProjectName    | ProjectActive | ProjectStageID |
+-----------+-------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
|         1 | K6674       | Ironworks      |      TRUE     |              5 |
|         2 | K6694       | Overstone Leys |      TRUE     |              5 |
|         3 | K6702       | Salt           |      TRUE     |              5 |
|         9 | K6678       | Dyers          |      TRUE     |              5 |
|        10 | K6397       | Chatham Road   |      TRUE     |              6 |
|        11 | K6691       | Kennel Grounds |      TRUE     |              1 |
|        12 | K6693       | Church Farm    |      TRUE     |              4 |
+-----------+-------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
```

ProjectStaff

```
+----------------+-----------+------------+---------------+
| ProjectStaffID | ProjectID | EmployeeID | ProjectRoleID |
+----------------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|              1 |         1 |         31 |             6 |
|              2 |         2 |         15 |             6 |
|              3 |         3 |         61 |             6 |
|              4 |         9 |         61 |             6 |
|              5 |        10 |         72 |             6 |
|              6 |        10 |         95 |            13 |
|              7 |        10 |         70 |            10 |
|              8 |        10 |          1 |            10 |
+----------------+-----------+------------+---------------+
```

ProjectRoles

```
+---------------+---------------------------+
| ProjectRoleID | ProjectRole               |
+---------------+---------------------------+
|             1 | Archaeologist             |
|             2 | Assistant Supervisor      |
|             3 | CAD Manager               |
|             4 | CAD Technician            |
|             5 | Photographer              |
|             6 | Project Manager           |
|             7 | Project Officer           |
|             8 | Senior Project   Officer  |
|             9 | Specialist                |
|            10 | Supervisor                |
|            11 | Surveyor                  |
|            12 | Trainee                   |
|            13 | Post-Excavation   Manager |
+---------------+---------------------------+
```

```
SELECT
  projectdetails.ProjectID,
  projectdetails.ProjectCode,
  projectdetails.SiteCode,
  (SELECT
     employees.EmpABB
    WHERE
      projectstaff.ProjectRoleID = 6) AS ProjectManager,
  (SELECT
      employees.EmpABB
    WHERE
      projectstaff.ProjectRoleID = 13) AS PostExManager,
  (SELECT
      employees.EmpABB
    WHERE
      projectstaff.ProjectRoleID = 10) AS Supervisor,
  projectdetails.ProjectName,
  projectdetails.ProjectActive,
  projectdetails.ProjectStageID,
  projectdetails.AuthorityID
FROM
  projectdetails
  LEFT JOIN projectstaff ON projectstaff.ProjectID = projectdetails.ProjectID
  INNER JOIN projectroles ON projectstaff.ProjectRoleID = projectroles.ProjectRoleID
  INNER JOIN employees ON employees.ProjectRoleID = projectroles.ProjectRoleID AND projectstaff.EmployeeID =
    employees.EmployeeID
GROUP By
  projectdetails.projectID
```

This produces the following table. It's displaying each project once but not displaying data for postex manager or Supervisor.
Example below:

```
+-----------+-------------+----------+----------------+---------------+------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
| ProjectID | ProjectCode | SiteCode | ProjectManager | PostExManager | Supervisor | ProjectName    | ProjectActive | ProjectStageID |
+-----------+-------------+----------+----------------+---------------+------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
|         1 | K6674       | RHN20    | AG             |               |            | Ironworks      |      TRUE     |              5 |
|         2 | K6694       |          | PC             |               |            | Overstone Leys |      TRUE     |              5 |
|         3 | K6702       |          | PCM            |               |            | Salt           |      TRUE     |              5 |
|         9 | K6678       |          | PCM            |               |            | Dyers          |      TRUE     |              5 |
|        10 | K6397       | KCWC19   | ZP             |               |            | Chatham Road   |      TRUE     |              6 |
|        11 | K6691       | KAKW20   | JW             |               |            | Kennel Grounds |      TRUE     |              1 |
|        12 | K6693       |          | PM             |               |            | Church Farm    |      TRUE     |              4 |
|           |             |          |                |               |            |                |               |                |
+-----------+-------------+----------+----------------+---------------+------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
```

But if I remove GROUP BY, it does display the other project Roles but separates out the data by adding additional rows.

```
+-----------+-------------+----------+----------------+---------------+------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
| ProjectID | ProjectCode | SiteCode | ProjectManager | PostExManager | Supervisor | ProjectName    | ProjectActive | ProjectStageID |
+-----------+-------------+----------+----------------+---------------+------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
|         1 | K6674       | RHN20    | AG             |               |            | Ironworks      |      TRUE     |              5 |
|         2 | K6694       |          | PC             |               |            | Overstone Leys |      TRUE     |              5 |
|         3 | K6702       |          | PCM            |               |            | Salt           |      TRUE     |              5 |
|         9 | K6678       |          | PCM            |               |            | Dyers          |      TRUE     |              5 |
|        10 | K6397       | KCWC19   | ZP             |               |            | Chatham Road   |      TRUE     |              6 |
|        10 | K6397       | KCWC19   |                | JB            |            | Kennel Grounds |      TRUE     |              6 |
|        10 | K6397       | KCWC19   |                |               | W Pool     | Church Farm    |      TRUE     |              6 |
|        10 | K6397       | KCWC19   |                |               | R Books    | March House    |      TRUE     |              6 |
+-----------+-------------+----------+----------------+---------------+----------
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query - and please never again post pictures of text

Comment: Thank you. I've corrected the post. I saw that earlier and tried it out but missed the Text Column.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my own question. Usual thing, you ask the question, relax, then the answer pops in your head. I'm not entirely sure why it works as I got the answer from another query in my list of queries which have worked before.

You use CASE

```
SELECT
  projectdetails.ProjectID,
  projectdetails.ProjectCode,
  projectdetails.SiteCode,
  max(case when projectstaff.ProjectRoleID = 6 then employees.EmpABB else null end) as ProjectManager,
  max(case when projectstaff.ProjectRoleID = 13 then employees.EmpABB else null end) as PostExManager,
  max(case when projectstaff.ProjectRoleID = 10 then employees.EmpABB else null end) as Supervisor,
  projectdetails.ProjectName,
  projectdetails.ProjectActive,
  projectdetails.ProjectStageID,
  projectdetails.AuthorityID
FROM
  projectdetails
  LEFT JOIN projectstaff ON projectstaff.ProjectID = projectdetails.ProjectID
  INNER JOIN projectroles ON projectstaff.ProjectRoleID = projectroles.ProjectRoleID
  INNER JOIN employees ON employees.ProjectRoleID = projectroles.ProjectRoleID AND projectstaff.EmployeeID =
    employees.EmployeeID
  GROUP BY 
 projectdetails.ProjectID
```

```
| ProjectID | ProjectCode | SiteCode | ProjectManager | PostExManager | Supervisor | ProjectName    | ProjectActive | ProjectStageID |
+-----------+-------------+----------+----------------+---------------+------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
|         1 | K6674       | RHN20    | AG             |               |            | Ironworks      |      TRUE     |              5 |
+-----------+-------------+----------+----------------+---------------+------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
|         2 | K6694       |          | PC             |               |            | Overstone Leys |      TRUE     |              5 |
+-----------+-------------+----------+----------------+---------------+------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
|         3 | K6702       |          | PCM            |               |            | Salt           |      TRUE     |              5 |
+-----------+-------------+----------+----------------+---------------+------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
|         9 | K6678       |          | PCM            |               |            | Dyers          |      TRUE     |              5 |
+-----------+-------------+----------+----------------+---------------+------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
|        10 | K6397       | KCWC19   | ZP             | JB            | W Pool     | Chatham Road   |      TRUE     |              6 |
+-----------+-------------+----------+----------------+---------------+------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
|        11 | K6691       | KAKW20   | JW             |               |            | Kennel Grounds |      TRUE     |              1 |
+-----------+-------------+----------+----------------+---------------+------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
|        12 | K6693       |          | PM             |               |            | Church Farm    |      TRUE     |              4 |
+-----------+-------------+----------+----------------+---------------+------------+-----
```

Comment: It's called rubber ducking: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Rubber%20ducking